# How to change font tty.js?

Tags: node.js, macos, fonts, tty

I have installed tty.js on my Mac (running 10.10.1) and can run tty.js and access the terminal window from my browser locally.

How can I modify the default tty.js font (I believe it is 'ptmono') and change it to another?

*(I am happy to modify the tty.js code if someone can inform me where to change it)*

Comment: nothing on https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/ suggests that's baked in functionality, but if there's any place on the web where you should ask this question, that would be the first place, since that's a thing you as user want to do, and so tty.js should either address as "can't be done", "can be done as ..." or "we're working on this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a web app, so it seems like [changing the font in the CSS](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/blob/master/static/style.css#L115) would do the trick.

Comment: I've tried changing this line but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: I take that back, I was changing the wrong style.css file and have just re-tried it on this one and it worked. Thanks.